# Show updated date only if different from published date in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Trying to show the published date, and the update date if it differs from published date, I tried this code in my wordpress template:

```
<p class="card-text">Published <?php the_date();?>.&nbsp;
<?php  
    if ( the_date( 'U' ) !== the_modified_date( 'U' ) ) {
        echo "Updated " . the_modified_date('F j, Y');
    }
    ?>
```

However i do net get any output. Possibly simple, but still I only get a very long number as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `get_the_date` and `get_the_modified_date` because they return the value and not printing it out.

```
if ( get_the_date( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_date( 'U' ) ) {
    echo "Updated " . get_the_modified_date('F j, Y');
}
```